# What is the command for this symbol?

Tags: symbols

[image]

I'm looking for a way to make the D figure in LaTeX. Please help :)

Comment: `\mathcal{D}(f)`

Comment: @Soer7022: Usually one does not grab comments by users and post them as answers without asking them before :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `\mathcal{D} (f)` -Credit Steven B. Segletes